# Can I extend external scss rule without including it in the output?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

GIVEN that there is existing scss file that defines rules like `.btn {..}` or `.btn-primary`...

I WANT to declare my own rules by extending existing rules

```
.my-button {
  @extend .btn
  @extend .btn-primary
}
```

**without actually including the `.btn` and `.btn-primary` classes in my generated css file?**

Normally I need to `@import exiting.scss`, but that includes all the rules from the file in my css  output.

Comment: Not trying to be smug, but isn't it just as simple as **not** doing what you normally do and simply don't @import and create your own rule-set in the final document? Seems to me you can't extend existing rules and not wanting to include the existing declarations. Mutual exclusive logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the only way to accomplish this would be to convert .btn to an extension (`%btn { .... }`) and extend that. Outside of that, maybe @use, but I haven't personally used that functionality yet, so I'm unsure if that is a viable option.

Comment: I would need some more information to better understand what you're looking for specifically. I assume you will be loading two CSS files... a Bootstrap CSS file and another CSS file which would include your `.my-button` rule. Is that correct? And you are trying to not have redundant code in the Bootrap and your own custom CSS files, correct?

Comment: @inki: no, I actually want just my custom css file. I.e. I won't use .btn-primary class anywhere

Comment: I agree with @Chaosxmk. Why not simply use mixins instead? See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_buttons.scss#L72 as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sass does not currently support this by default, neither with the @import nor @use rule.

Nonetheless, if you (can) use npm packages ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) / [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/)) in your project, then [node-sass-magic-importer](https://github.com/maoberlehner/node-sass-magic-importer) may come in handy for you.

In your example, you could do the following:

```
@import '{ .btn, .btn-primary } from ~bootstrap';

.my-button {
  @extend .btn
  @extend .btn-primary
}
```

Note that the above will not do *exactly* what you desire – it will still import the other two classes though at least not the entire stylesheet. If you'd still like to go one step further, you could do:

```
@import '{ .btn as .my-button } from /bootstrap/_buttons.scss';
@import '[variables] from /bootstrap/_variables.scss';
@import '[mixins] from /bootstrap/mixins/_buttons.scss';

.my-button {
  @include button-variant($btn-primary-color, $btn-primary-bg, $btn-primary-border);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend you to use [@mixins and @include](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) for this.

Although because as you said in your question, you are using an existing file (probably third party) that defines this rules. It may be tedious to turn the classes from this file into mixins.

so if you are going to use only a few classes from this file I recommend you to do that.

You will have to turn:

```css
.btn{
/*
some cool styles
*/
}
```

into:

```
@mixin{
/*
cooler styles
*/
}
```

but still mixins as declared in the [Sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) do exactly what you want.

source code SCSS:

```
@mixin reset-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

@mixin horizontal-list {
  @include reset-list;

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: {
      left: -2px;
      right: 2em;
    }
  }
}

nav ul {
  @include horizontal-list;
}
```

result CSS:

```css
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -2px;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you import as @import in scss and when you do a production build the webpack dependancy graph will only include it once at the top level as it becomes a common chunk since you are using it in multiple places. Yes there is a side effect that unused scss is also included as there isn't much of tree shaking that is done.

Hence it should not affect the production build.

Comment: Are you sure that is the case? I get errors like: `component.scss exceeded maximum budget. Budget 100.00 kB was not met by 116.25 kB with a total of 216.25 kB.` - which to me indicates that what you have suggested does not happen.?

Comment: The message is basically showcasing what I have mentioned above that unused SCSS are not removed. This causes bloating of the file hence the message above.
Here if u increase the allowable chunk size then it should work fine.